# Windows Command line script decrementing variables in FOR loop based on a user defined starting variable

Tags: windows, command-line, for-loop, batch-file

I'm trying to write what seemed like an easy script but I can't figure it out.

Basically, a user is asked Question 1: "How many (in this case) video files they want to add together to create 1 big video file?"

The user then gets asked Question 2: "what is the name of the file you want to add together?"  Now here is the problem I'm having...

How do I create a for loop that asks that Question 2 the amount of times given in the 1st question and saves each answer as a unique variable (I'm guessing at decrementation of the variable)

after I have all the correct file names from the user then the program will call the video program according to the video program syntax (THAT syntax I don't need help with, I understand that part)

ex.  (a "?" means i don't know what to put there)

@echo off

set /p howmany=How many files do you want to add?

for /? %%variable(???) in (%howmany%???) do (set /p inputfilename=what is the name of the first file you want to add? inputfilename=filename set %howmany%-1???=%howmany%????)

so if the user answered 5 to the Question 1, then the for loop should ask Question 2 five times and create 5 unique variables for every time the answer is given.  inputfilename1 = movie1.mov inputfilename2 = movie2.mov etc..

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days.. I can't rap my head around it.  I've done plenty of for commands before but this has got me stumped.  My browser history is full of google searches that seems like something people would ask about any kind of files.  If I did find anything remotely close to this question it was always asked for a different programming language.  My brain is fried. Is this even something possible?  Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Martin's answer describe how to *create* the unique variables, he didn't explained how to *read* them. When you are talking about "saves each answer as a unique variable" the involved concept here is *ARRAY*. You need to use Delayed Expansion in order to get the values of the unique variables ("array elements"); for further details, type `set /?` and look for "delayed expansion". You may read a detailed description about array management in Batch files at this post: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p howmany=How many files do you want to add?
for /L %%i in (1,1,%howmany%) do (
   set /p inputfilename[%%i]=what is the name of the file you want to add?
)

rem Process array elements (just show them in this case)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%howmany%) do (
   echo %%i- !inputfilename[%%i]!
)
```

The example below may help you in understanding array management in an easier way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create an array of ordinal terms
set i=0
for %%a in (first second third fourth fifth sixth) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set term[!i!]=%%a
)
rem Previous FOR is equivalent to: set term[1]=first, set term[2]=second, ...

set /p howmany=How many files do you want to add?
for /L %%i in (1,1,%howmany%) do (
   set /p inputfilename[%%i]=what is the name of the !term[%%i]! file you want to add?
)

rem Process array elements (just show them in this case)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%howmany%) do (
   echo The !term[%%i]! file is !inputfilename[%%i]!
)
```

Comment: I read your detailed explanation and it's great!  I'm bookmarking that description of Arrays! I would've "upped" it but unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet. :(  I also read your comment and I completely agree with you. I don't understand why ANYONE thinks that bashing any programming language should be considered "helpful". I really appreciate you taking the time to help potential programmers understand how to do things not just do it for them.  Thank you.

Comment: +1, in most cases it's possible to work with "arrays" and without `delayed expansion` or "toggeling" it to preserve exclamation marks, but it's really SLOW.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway to answer your actual question:

```
@echo off

set /p howmany=How many files do you want to add? 

for /L %%i in (1, 1, %howmany%) do (
set /p inputfilename%%i=what is the name of the first file you want to add? 
)

rem Output the variables to check
set inputfilename
```

Output:

```
How many files do you want to add? 3
what is the name of the first file you want to add? first
what is the name of the first file you want to add? second
what is the name of the first file you want to add? third
inputfilename1=first
inputfilename2=second
inputfilename3=third
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.    I think this is exactly what I need. thank you!  I will test this later tonight and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need those N variables for? I would guess you need to pass a list of filenames to some script/command-line application.

So, wouldn't you better do with one variable with (space?-)delimited list of filenames?

Like:

```
@echo off

set /p howmany=How many files do you want to add?

set list=

:NEXT

if %howmany% leq 0 goto END

set /p inputfilename=what is the name of the first file you want to add? 

set list=%list% "%inputfilename%"
set /a howmany=%howmany% - 1
goto NEXT

:END

echo %list%
```